# Applications of degenerate parabolic equations

Tags: applications, inverse-problems, parabolic-pde

I study inverse problems for degenerate parabolic equations, specifically cases when the unknown major coefficient in the equations vanishes at $t=0$, e.g.:

$u_t = t^{\beta}a(t)\Delta u + f$

What processes (in physics/finance/etc.) do such equations describe?

Thanks in advance!